# Ubuntu crash after shred command disk

Tags: crash, shredding

I have a dual boot ubuntu 19.10 with windows 10 and erased hdd disk for windows. I also tried to erase ssd disk with Ubuntu OS on it using shred but it crashed midway.
Now I cannot boot into ubuntu it gets stuck on loading screen. Something it never did before. I tried most of the advanced recovery mode options but nothing helps. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: So, you shredded the drive with your OS on it, and now you cannot boot?

Comment: You have deleted (shredded ) your Ubuntu OS so you can't boot. Reinstall OS will fix the problem. Why did you shred both OSs in the first place?

Comment: I imagine you wanted to shred/delete a partition that your OS was not on.  It is very important to know which partition is which and to double and triple check before changing/doing anything to any partition.